# SP Designer list edit form not updating the fields when click on save button

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-list, edit-form

i have one sharepoint custom list with 2 edit forms created by using SPD, one is default and another one is calling on default edit form by using input button control.

Issue: when i click on input control from default edit form, another edit form is opening as popup, i am entering required information over here, then after clicking the save button in popup edit form only fields those are in popup form are updating not on default edit form fields.

any one could you plz help on this how to update the fields in default edit form under save button.